# xmlelement is not working in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.25 version. My problem is bean properties are not working if I use `@XmlElement`

I have added all the jackson jars and configure jackson mapper also.

Below is my pom.xml

```
 <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
//Configuration Class

    @Bean
        public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
            return (mapperBuilder) -> mapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        }
```

Test.java

```
@XmlRootElement
puiblic class Test {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String identifier;

//Getter and Setter
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String printTest(@RequestBody Test test) {
        LOGGER.debug(" Test {}",test.getId());
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I am hitting the request with

```
{"id" : "1"}
```

I am getting null pointer exception.

When I am hitting the request with

```
{"identifier" : "1"}
```

I am getting the response

hello.

Why the `@XmlElement` annotations not working in my spring boot project.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: XML != JSON. THe xml mappings don't influence the json mapping.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks, But the same thing I used with jersey its worked. Why spring boot is not working. Can you suggest any alternative approach for this issue

Comment: By using the jackson annotations or send XML instead of JSON.

Comment: for using jackson annotations. I want to have different name in json and bean property. It should bind based on the key value present in the annotation

Comment: Again use the jackson annotation to specify the name NOT the jaxb annotation.

Comment: jackson annotation is working as expected. In case if i have to send the xml response i have to add @xmlelement is it correct?

Comment: that depends on the xml marshaling you use. for Jaxb that is the one, if you only use Jackson you don't.

Comment: Ok Thanks @M.Deinum, for giving the clarity about marshaling